# How to create marginal effects tables in R?

Tags: r, graphics, latex, logistic-regression, glm

I have three ordered regression models where the ordered dependent variable ranges from 0 to 2. What I want to do is create marginal effects tables (not a plot) at each level (0, 1, and 2) for all three models. So, three tables with each showing the marginal effects at level 0, 1, and 2.

```
    ## create a random data that is similar to my dataset
    set.seed(100)
    mydata <- data.frame(
      x1    = sample(c(0, 1, 2), 100, replace = TRUE),
      x2    = sample(c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4), 100, replace = TRUE),
      x3    = sample(c(0, 1, 2, 3, 5), 100, replace = TRUE),
      x4    = sample(c(1:100), 100, replace = TRUE),
      x5    = sample(c(10:1000), 100, replace = TRUE),
      Z1 = sample(c(0, 1, 2), 100, replace = TRUE)
    )


    ## makeit factor
    mydata$Z1 <- as.factor(mydata$Z1)

    ## My models
    require(MASS)

    M1<- polr(Z1 ~x1+x2+x3+x4, data=mydata, Hess = TRUE,  method="logistic")

    M2<- polr(Z1 ~x2+x3+x4+x5, data=mydata, Hess = TRUE,  method="logistic")

    M3<- polr(Z1 ~x1+x2+x3+x4+x5, data=mydata, Hess = TRUE,  method="logistic")

    ## Calculate marginal effects using the erer package
    require(erer)

    M1ME<- ocME(M1)

    M2ME <- ocME(M2)

    M3ME <- ocME(M3)
```

Usually I would use the package `stargazer` to create proper tables, for example using:

```
stargazer(M1,M2, M3, type = ”text”)
```

However, the output from the OcME()  does not generate the same type of tables and nor can I generate tables at each level:
 `stargazer(M1ME$out,M2ME$out, M3ME$out,  type = "text" )`

- Do you have any suggestion as to how to generate these types of
  tables? Very time-consuming to do this manually.

**EDIT:** 
So the desirable output is to create three tables indicated below(note: numbers are not correct, just an illustration)

**Marginal Effects - Level 0 (Z)**

```
 ==========================================
                      Dependent variable:     
                 -----------------------------
                              Z1              
                    (1)       (2)       (3)   
    ------------------------------------------
    x1             0.301               0.302  
                  (0.250)             (0.250) 

    x2             0.143     0.174     0.142  
                  (0.131)   (0.128)   (0.132) 

    x3             0.121     0.106     0.122  
                  (0.117)   (0.116)   (0.117) 

    x4            -0.008    -0.008    -0.008  
                  (0.007)   (0.007)   (0.007) 

    x5                     -0.00004   -0.0001 
                            (0.001)   (0.001) 

    ------------------------------------------
    Observations    100       100       100   
    ==========================================
    Note:          *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

**Marginal effects -- Level 1 (Z)**

```
==========================================
                  Dependent variable:     
             -----------------------------
                          Z1              
                (1)       (2)       (3)   
------------------------------------------
x1             0.301               0.302  
              (0.250)             (0.250) 

x2             0.143     0.174     0.142  
              (0.131)   (0.128)   (0.132) 

x3             0.121     0.106     0.122  
              (0.117)   (0.116)   (0.117) 

x4            -0.008    -0.008    -0.008  
              (0.007)   (0.007)   (0.007) 

x5                     -0.00004   -0.0001 
                        (0.001)   (0.001) 

------------------------------------------
Observations    100       100       100   
==========================================
Note:          *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

**Marginal effects --Level 3 (Z)**

```
==========================================
                  Dependent variable:     
             -----------------------------
                          Z1              
                (1)       (2)       (3)   
------------------------------------------
x1             0.301               0.302  
              (0.250)             (0.250) 

x2             0.143     0.174     0.142  
              (0.131)   (0.128)   (0.132) 

x3             0.121     0.106     0.122  
              (0.117)   (0.116)   (0.117) 

x4            -0.008    -0.008    -0.008  
              (0.007)   (0.007)   (0.007) 

x5                     -0.00004   -0.0001 
                        (0.001)   (0.001) 

------------------------------------------
Observations    100       100       100   
==========================================
Note:          *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

Comment: What type of output are you looking for? Stargazer just spits out LaTeX or html code, so you can tweak it yourself as you see fit...

Comment: Hi Cyrus! That's correct, I thought there might be a way to tweak it anyway..I want basically a stargazer-like output, they look nice and proper to me (publication-quality tables). I have no experience in LaTeX unfortunately.

Comment: You need to explain the output you want...Stargazer works fine for me when using the data you supplied. Not sure what you're looking for. You need to be as specific as possible when using stack overflow

Comment: also checkout ``xtable``

Answer (score 0):

New developmental package on Github gets at this a bit. By Thomas Leeper who posts around here quite a bit.

https://github.com/leeper/margins

Enjoy!

Comment: more of  a suggestion than an answer, post this as a comment instead !